# Can't find license information for the Twitter @anywhere JSDK - does anyone know?

Tags: javascript, twitter, licensing, twitter-anywhere

I need to provide licensing information for each 3rd party script I'm including in a website but I can't seem to find license information for Twitter's [@anywhere JSDK](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome) script.

I've found the [Facebook JSDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk) license on github, licensed under the  Apache License Version 2.0.

So, I've tweeted some Twitter developers and they have not responded, so I figured I'd post the question here.

Also - is this a better topic for meta.stackoverflow.com not entirely sure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is  not about programming but about licensing.

Comment: You should recommend a better place for it then instead of just closing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the code likely falls under the general Twitter [Developer API Terms](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms). Your use of it also falls under the Twitter [TOS](http://twitter.com/tos), as per section 1:

> 1. All use of the Twitter API and content, documentation, code, and related materials made available to you on or through Twitter ("Twitter Content") is subject to and must comply with these Rules. As a reminder, you and your Service are subject to the [Twitter Terms of Service](http://twitter.com/tos).

Comment: Thanks I guess I'll just provide a link to their TOS as a resource for "licensing information".